# How can I access a JSON integer value after conversion to Python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I'm currently creating a simple app in Python and stumbled across the following problem;

This code currently results in a server error:

```
uResponse = requests.get(uri)
data = json.loads(Jresponse)
test = data['items']['latestReading']['value']
return test
```

However, I know from returning just `.latestReading` that the key for **value** does exist.

```
uResponse = requests.get(uri)
data = json.loads(Jresponse)
test = data['items']['latestReading']
return test
```

> **test** = {"@id":"XXX","date":"XXX","dateTime":"XXX","measure":"XXX","value":4.321}

**id, date, dateTime, measure** all return their relative values of XXX. I presume that 'Value' doesn't because it's not being recognised as it isn't a string?

All I'm trying to do is return the value of 'Value' - Any advise?

Comment: are you using "value" or "Value"?

Comment: What is your error when run this `data['items']['latestReading']['value']`?

Comment: @shotgunner If I run data['items']['latestReading']['value'] i receive a 500 server error. If I remove the ['value'] or replace ['value'] with any other key, I receive the expected output.

Comment: @someusername01 Can you show us your server side code related to the error ?

Comment: @shotgunner

`@app.route('/')
def index():
    #return render_template('index.html')
    uri = "XXX"
    try:
        uResponse = requests.get(uri)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
       return "Connection Error"
       
    Jresponse = uResponse.text
    data = json.loads(Jresponse)

    test = data['items']['latestReading']['value']
    return test`

Answer (score 0):

`data['items']['latestReading']['value']` returns an integer, which cannot be returned directly to index for some reason.

Casting as string `str(data['items']['latestReading']['value'])` seems to work.